# Obter títulos das janelas abertas

Tags: c, c++, windows, winapi

Tenho um programa em C++ que chega em certa parte que eu preciso verificar se uma janela está aberta, se sim executa uma parte do código.

Como eu conseguiria pegar as janelas abertas e fazer essa verificação?

> Achei um link que poderia ajudar nessa questão, a resposta de baixo me ajudou sim, mas para pessoas no futuro vou deixar este link -> [Listar Janelas Abertas No Windows](http://www.devmedia.com.br/listar-as-janelas-abertas-no-windows-c/23629) É Em C# Mas Existe Funções Nativas Da `WinAPI` Então É De Boa.

Comment: Poste uma parte do código do que você já tentou. Está utilizando algum framework/biblioteca?

Comment: O Problema É Que Ainda Não Tentei Pq Não Sei. Não, Estou Usando C++ Normal Só A <iostream> e <Windows.h>

Comment: USar `<windows.h>` não é usar C++ normal.

Comment: É Eu Sei aushua, Vacilei Msm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que isto resolve o que você deseja:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    char class_name[80];
    char title[80];
    GetClassName(hwnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
    GetWindowText(hwnd,title,sizeof(title));
    cout <<"Window title: "<<title<<endl;
    cout <<"Class name: "<<class_name<<endl<<endl;    
    return TRUE;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/GetWindows.c).

Se não fizer exatamente o que você quer o caminho é este para adaptar.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

De acordo com os comentário eu achei [essa outra solução no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292674/221800) que filtra as janelas que estão ativas. Ela está em C e é mais complexa mas parece resolver pelo menos parte do problema.

Comment: Isto quer dizer que funcionou? Só não está apresentando todas e apresenta algumas que não estão ativas? Posso ver se descobro algo sobre isto. Mas o caminho inicial está aí.

Comment: Sim, Mas A Questão É Que **Muitas Mesmo** São Inativas, Só Deu Um Warning -> `warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 2 of
'BOOL EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC, LPARAM)' [-Wconversion-null] Isso Aqui É A Linha De Código -> EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);`

Comment: Você Sabe Porque Algumas Janelas Não Aparece O Título ? Apareceram Muitas Janelas Só Que 100% Ou 90% São Janelas Que Não Aparecem Realmente Para O Usuário, Tipo Eu Estou Com O Windows Media Player Aberto E Ele Não Foi Citado Na Saída.

Comment: Já Consegui O Resultado Que Queria Só Mudei Um Pouco Este Código, Não Sei Porque Agora Começou A Aparecer Algumas Telas Ativas, Valeu.